# IOException with CSSLexer when trying to launchIOSDevice using Eclipse and Gluon

Tags: java, ios, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I've successfully tested a simple Gluon Mobile app on Desktop, Android devices and emulators as well as on an iOS emulator. However when launching : launchIOSDevice I get the following error:

> IOException with com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSLexer$$Lambda$25: null

And the (reduced) stacktrace

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':launchIOSDevice'.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IOException with com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSLexer$$Lambda$25: null
>
> Caused by: java.io.EOFException

I get the exact same error when try :createIpa. 
I have tried different Java and Gradle versions as well as multiple projects, but nothing seems to be portable to an iOS device.

I'm using

> 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'

and

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Has anyone encountered a similar error?

Comment: Is it the default template from the Gluon plugin or have you modified it? Can you post the css file (if you have modified it) and the full stacktrace?

Comment: @JoséPereda The project in question is [Notes](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/notes) and I haven't modified anything but rather just tried to launch it on the iOS device. Here are the 
[Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a5908ec5360411a7a4d049f0757c9cd)
and the [Gradle](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/283175507707ecf7f97a4350fb507732)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Which is your OS and which JDK version are you using?

Comment: @JoséPereda Here is the complete [stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9651f7ef3a15a6f109b2c9189635b0b8) I'm using jdk1.8.0_144.jdk, MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1, Eclipse Java EE Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1)

Comment: I'd say something went wrong with a file, based on the `java.io.EOFException`. Try cleaning first your project (`./gradlew clean`), removing the `.gradle` folder as well. If the problem persist, you'll have to remove the cache and build it again. You should find them here: `/Users/<user>/.robovm/cache/ios/arm64/release/Users/<user>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/<.>/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar/com/sun/javafx/css/parser`.

Comment: In the folder above I have `CSSLexer$$Lambda$25.class.o`, with 5376 bytes, up to `CSSLexer$$Lambda$47.class.o`.

Comment: @JoséPereda I have only up to CSSLexer$$Lambda$24.class.o. Will try to generate the missing ones and come back with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to delete the contents of the following folder
`/Users/<user>/.robovm/cache/ios/arm64/release/Users/<user>/.‌​gradle/caches/module‌​s-2/files-2.1/org.ja‌​vafxports/ios-sdk/8.‌​60.9/<.>/unpacked/io‌​s-sdk/rt/lib/ext/jfx‌​rt.jar/com/sun/javaf‌​x/css/parser`

and rerun `:clean` and `:launchIOSDevice`

The folder should contain up to `CSSLexer$$Lambda$47.class.o` for the grade task to build successfully.